# SVG internationalization (generate .svg for several languages)

Tags: vector-graphics, svg, localization

I have an SVG file and want to maintain it in several languages.

I am currently using Inkscape and does not seem to have any such feature.

The SVG standard has [internationalization](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/i18n.html) [parts](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/i18n.html) but it sounds like a different thing.

I would be OK with a pre-processor, or any other solution.

Requirements:

- Produces valid SVG files
- Runs on Linux
- No (or not too much) SVG source manual editing
- Not too expensive, preferably free, ideally open source